# What is the lowest temperature that a thermocouple can respond to?

Tags: temperature, thermoelectricity

I am trying to find out if a thermocouple could detect low temperatures like 40 or 37 degrees centigrade, it's been really difficult for me to find it, for I'm just an O'level graduate.

Comment: You can use thermocouples all the way down to cryogenic temperatures. It is important to understand that there are always two thermocouples in your system: the one at the temperature you want to measure and the other one at a reference temperature. In applications in which precision doesn't matter too much, the reference thermocouple is usually replaced by an electronic normal voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Thermocouples work due to Seebeck effect, which couples heat flow to charge flow. If you wish to see which type of thermocouple applies to different temperature ranges just open wikipedia:

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple)

Comment: can the first type of thermocouple produce emf at the temperatute difference btn the room temperature and maybe 37 celcius (difference of 10)

Comment: In principle yes. however, your readings are just as good as your voltage measurement equipment. Plus usual thermocouples have deviation or "jumps" all the time. The standard deviation will also depend on how did you make them, by soldering or by welding, and it depends on the quality of your work (I assume that you by the cable and weld yourself).

Comment: The concept is the smaller the temp difference the high Seebeck constant you want.

Comment: well,big up ,thank you ,i also tried to look for some videos on youtube,and i learned that all i'm thinking is very possible,thank you,My God and my all

Answer (score 0):

you can use it at any temperature you want, but the problem is the linearity which makes that at some temperatures for some couple types, you will get a lower Δv for the same Δt° and lower accuracy. On the contrary, however, this also have a benefit if those are the temperatures for the cold junction, because it reduces the need for a cold junction compensation (eg : According with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple#Type_B), this is the case for type B thermocouples which lose all sensibility around 21°C)